# Can I run 'sudo apt autoremove' safley?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude

I'm just wondering if I can run `sudo apt autoremove` with the following packages installed. I have run it a number of times before on ubuntu and I am on a laptop and sometimes the GUI fails, sound card does not work or some packages just break. So I just wanted to double check this time.

```
~ $ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblept5 libnvidia-cfg1-435 libnvidia-cfg1-455 libnvidia-common-435 libnvidia-common-455 libnvidia-compute-435 libnvidia-compute-435:i386
  libnvidia-compute-455 libnvidia-compute-455:i386 libnvidia-decode-435 libnvidia-decode-435:i386 libnvidia-decode-455 libnvidia-decode-455:i386
  libnvidia-encode-435 libnvidia-encode-435:i386 libnvidia-encode-455 libnvidia-encode-455:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-435 libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-455
  libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 libnvidia-gl-435 libnvidia-gl-435:i386 libnvidia-gl-455 libnvidia-gl-455:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-435 libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386
  libnvidia-ifr1-455 libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libqt5multimedia5 libqt5positioning5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5
  libqt5quickwidgets5 libqt5sensors5 libqt5webchannel5 libqt5webkit5 libtesseract4 linux-headers-5.4.0-42-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-47-generic
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-47 linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic
  linux-modules-5.4.0-47-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-47-generic nvidia-compute-utils-435 nvidia-compute-utils-455
  nvidia-dkms-435 nvidia-dkms-455 nvidia-kernel-common-435 nvidia-kernel-common-455 nvidia-kernel-source-435 nvidia-kernel-source-455 nvidia-utils-435
  nvidia-utils-455 python3.8-minimal qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects qml-module-qtquick-controls qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-layouts
  qml-module-qtquick-privatewidgets qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2 tesseract-ocr-eng tesseract-ocr-osd xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Generally* `apt` is quite good at knowing which packages are no longer required, but it’s good to see I’m not the only one who reads through the list to see what’s being removed before pulling the trigger

To answer the question, it will probably be better to look through the packages as groups:

- The nvidia 435 and 455 packages can be removed if you have the 460 (or newer) package installed
- The `Linux`-prefixed packages have all been replaced with newer software
- The Qt-based packages I’m not 100% certain of, as a lot of software uses those libraries. You may want to use `apt list --installed` to see if you have a newer version installed

As always, it’s a good idea to keep reliable backups handy in the event of a hiccup

Comment: How do you mean "keep a backup"?

Comment: Do you have a backup plan in place for your computer? If so, then a broken update can often be reversed in a matter of minutes (with practice). If you do not keep backups and things break … that’s not a fun day 

Comment: I keep backups of my data, just not my OS's

Answer (score 1):

`apt autoremove` will remove files that are still on your system but are no longer needed because the application that required them is no longer installed, that's why you receive:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required
```

It is safe and recommended executing `sudo apt autoremove`.